# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^a x^{v/2} e^{-\alpha x} J_v(2\beta\sqrt{x}) dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I'm searching for a way to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_0^a x^{v/2} e^{-\alpha x} J_v(2\beta\sqrt{x}) dx$$

where $J_v(x)$ are the Bessel-functions, and $v \in \mathbb{N}, (a,\beta) \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. The integral has a closed form when $a \to \infty$ (Gradshteyn/Ryzhik). However, is there also a way to solve the integral with a general upper interval-limit?

Comment: If you could do this for general $a$, you'd have a closed-form antiderivative for the integrand.  I don't think that's likely.

Comment: What you get by expanding $J_\nu$ as a Taylor series and integrate it termwise against $x^{\nu/2}e^{-\alpha x}$ is a series of incomplete Gamma functions.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the parameters?

Comment: @DavidH I added the domains of the paramters. There is no obvious other constraint that I could give.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sounds interesting, I will try to see how that could help. Thanks.